# redis pub/sub model for notification system with selective pushing

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I'm looking to build a notification system like facebook where my application logic (publisher) will push notifications generated by all users to the redis system.

```
User 1 --------------> Redis (Channel : notifications)
User 2 --------------> Redis (Channel : notifications)
User 3 --------------> Redis (Channel : notifications)
```

As you can see above, all the activity generated by users 1,2,3 are sent to the same channel notifications.

I have a node.js /socket.io server listening to redis as a subscriber for these notifications. (subscribed to channel **notifications**)

Now, **How do I selectively push only certain notifications to certain subscribers ?** Like facebook notifications, I will get notifications only for private messages sent to me, not for messages sent to others.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create personal channel per user, e.g., notifications.User1, notifications.User2, ...,
and make each user subscribe his/her channel.
(You don't need to worry of the channels' size.)

If the users are sharing one redis connection,
You may need to identify the receiver user from the channel name whenever the connection receives any subscription message.

**UPDATE:**

I assume this scenario:

Your nodejs app may know the user's id when the user logs in your app.
Then, your app subscribes the channel for the user only, e.g., like this:
(this is kind of pseudo-code, I'm not sure of nodejs.)

```
onUserLoggedIn(string userId) {
...
string userChannel = "notifications.user." + userId;

// If userId == "yash",
// then userChannel == "notifications.user.yash"

redisConnection.command("subscribe", userChannel);
...
}
```

And when your connection is received a published message from your redis server:

```
onMessagePublished(string channel, string message) {
    ...
    // You can get userId from channel id.
    vector<string> tokens = parseTokensFromChannel(channel);

    // If channel == "notifications.user.yash",
    // tokens == {"notifications", "user", "yash"};

    if (tokens[0] == "notifications") {
        if (tokens[1] == "user") {
            ...
            string userId = tokens[2];
            onMessagePublishedForUser(userId, message);
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

onMessagePublishedForUser(string userId, string message) {
// You can handle the message for each user.
// I don't think your user may need it's own handling code per user.

...
}
```

In this scenario, you don't need any hard-coding at all.
Your redis connection can subscribe any redis channels by simply sending command 'subscribe'.
I assume your user will send custom identifiable user information(at least the user's id) to the nodejs server so that your nodejs app can make the channel name dynamic.
(If your user will not send the user's id, how do you identify each user?)

Comment: I'm a little new to node.js so I'm not sure whether this is correct, but the channel to which the nodejs app is subscribed to is hardcoded in the code, correct ? So how will the same nodejs script subscribe to different channels ? Can the user send custom identifiable user information to the nodejs server so that I can make the channel name dynamic ?

Comment: @YashDesai: I updated my answer for your complementary questions. (*)